# macOS Terminal: How do I edit an MP3 file's metadata after renaming?

Tags: terminal, macos, file-metadata

I have a script using variables already renaming files to the following format:

```
(track#) - (title) - (artist) - (date).mp3
```

```bash
#! /bin/zsh -
set -o extendedglob
pattern='(#b)*_ \((<0-999>)\)(* )—( * )(<1-12>)_(<1-31>)_(<1900-2100>)(.mp3)'
ret=0
for file {
  if [[ $file = $~pattern ]] {
    argv=( "$match[@]" )
    mv -i -- $file "${(l[3][0])1} -$2-$3- $6-${(l[2][0])5}-${(l[2][0])4}-0900$7" || ret=$?
  }
}
exit $ret
```

Using this script, this file:

```
Public Talks_ (9) Walking With God Brings Blessings Now and Forever — Chris Ruscher 10_28_2023.mp3
```

is renamed to:

```
009 - Walking With God Brings Blessings Now and Forever - Chris Ruscher - 2023-28-10-0900.mp3
```

The format is: track# - title - artist - date.mp3, showing the variables: `$1 - $2 - $3 - $6-$5-$4-0900$7`.

**All of the above works flawlessly.** I now want to add to that script.

I would like to then insert those values into the metadata seen below.

1. track, which is held in `$1` >> `kMDItemAudioTrackNumber`
2. title, which is held in `$2` >> `kMDItemTitle`
3. artist, which is held in `$3` >> `kMDItemAuthors`
4. timestamp, which is a concatenate of these: `$6${(l[2][0])5}${(l[2][0])4}0900` >> `kMDItemContentCreationDate`

The script would also modify the file creation date to `kMDItemContentCreationDate`. I tried adding the `touch -t` command to the loop for this last step above (4) but it didn't work.

```
#! /bin/zsh -
set -o extendedglob
pattern='(#b)*_ \((<0-999>)\)(* )—( * )(<1-12>)_(<1-31>)_(<1900-2100>)(.mp3)'
ret=0
for file {
  if [[ $file = $~pattern ]] {
    argv=( "$match[@]" )
>   fecha=( "$6${(l[2][0])5}${(l[2][0])4}0900$7" )
>   touch -t $(date -j -f "%Y%m%d%H%M" $fecha +%Y%m%d%H%M) $file
    mv -i -- $file "${(l[3][0])1} -$2-$3- $6-${(l[2][0])5}-${(l[2][0])4}-0900$7" || ret=$?
  }
}
exit $ret
```

Please note this is for macOS using zsh in the terminal.

Any ideas with these two issues: editing the metadata and then adjusting the creation date? I am new to scripting so I have cobbled together what I have found on the forum. Your insight is much appreciated.

Comment: your posting of the filename into a "qoutation" field seems to have replace minus `-` with longer dashes `–`. Please check your question to verify we're talking about the right kind of hyphens, and problems don't simply stem from the wrong symbol being used.

Comment: The original em dashes were correct. The renaming portion of the script has worked perfectly without any issues. I am really asking on how to use the variables from that first step to edit the metadata and also to set the creation date of the file in the same script. Do you have any ideas? Thanks for checking by the way.

Comment: I edited the question to be clearer. Let me know if it is better or needs more clarification. Thanks again.